# Create unsearchable field in opensearch template

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have follow configuration for template:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "source": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    },
    "application_name": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    },
    "message": {
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

And i want to create unsearchable field, for example `application_name`. I try to add `enabled: false`, but this doesn't work.
How to create unsearchable field in template?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your text field to be unsearchable, you need to use the [`index` mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) and set it to false (it is true by default):

```
"application_name": {
  "type": "text",
  "index": false
},
```

Comment: any luck with this?